# different lines in two files when ignoring last column - in bash

Tags: bash, comparison, diff

I have two files, smaller and bigger and bigger contains all lines of smaller. Those lines are almost same, just last column differs.

```
file_smaller
  A NM 0
  B GT 4

file_bigger
  A NM 5 <-same as in file_smaller according to my rules
  C TY 2
  D OP 6
  B GT 3 <-same as in file_smaller according to my rules
```

I would like to write lines, where the two files differ, that means:

```
wished_output
  C TY 2
  D OP 6
```

Could you please help me to do so? Thanks a lot.

Comment: technically, in your example the file_bigger contains none of the lines of file_smaller since they differ in the last column.This can be confusing.

Comment: yes, I know. In my real data, they always differ in last column. But _only_ in last column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
cat file_bigger file_smaller |sed 's=\(.*\).$=\1='|sort| uniq -u > temp_pat
grep -f temp_pat file_bigger ; rm temp_pat
```

which will (in the same order)

- merge the files
- remove the last column
- sort the result
- print only unique lines in temp_pat
- find the original lines in file_bigger

all in all, the expected result.

Comment: briliant solution, indeed. works perfect with my testing data. thanks. however, one more question: how can I modify sed to work with 15 columns? "103621 3.8 0.0 0.0 LjChr3 5394580 5407424 (84580304) + ATLANTYS_LC_I-int LTR/Gypsy 1 12848 (0) 18" and "103621 3.8 0.0 0.0 LjChr3 5394580 5407424 (84580304) + ATLANTYS_LC_I-int LTR/Gypsy 1 12848 (0) 5" are same lines in this case.

Comment: @Perlnika Just add 15 dots instead of one at the sed command :) .That is, use `cat file_bigger file_smaller |sed 's=\(.*\)...............$=\1='|sort| uniq -u > temp_pat
grep -f temp_pat file_bigger ; rm temp_pat` or, more easily: `cat file_bigger file_smaller |sed 's=\(.*\).\{15\}$=\1='|sort| uniq -u > temp_pat
grep -f temp_pat file_bigger ; rm temp_pat`     Sorry for the mess:)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FILENAME==file_bigger {arr[$1 $2]=$0}
     FILENAME==file_smaller { tmp=$1 $2;  if( tmp in arr) {next} else {print $0}}
    ' file_bigger file_smaller
```

See if that meets you needs

Comment: need to quote the filename in the first 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -vf <(cut -d " " -f 1-2 file_smaller| sed 's/^/^/') file_bigger
```

The process substitution results in this:

```
^A NM
^B GT
```

Then, `grep -v` removes those patterns from "file_bigger"

Answer (score 0):

Bash 4 using associative arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

f() {
    if (( $# != 2 )); then
        echo "usage: ${FUNCNAME} <smaller> <bigger>" >&2
        return 1
    fi

    local -A smaller
    local -a x

    while read -ra x; do
        smaller["${x[@]::2}"]=0
    done <"$1"

    while read -ra x; do
        ((${smaller["${x[@]::2}"]:-1})) && echo "${x[*]}"
    done <"$2"
}

f /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/0 <<"SMALLER" 3<&0 <<"BIGGER"
A NM 0
B GT 4
SMALLER
A NM 5
C TY 2
D OP 6
B GT 3
BIGGER
```